# Angular 6 - Directive Output is firing for all components in the same moment

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular2-directives

I have a form with four datePicker components, users are only allowed to select the date from the calendar but they cannot edit it. I've created a directive that allows to cancel the date when user clicks on canc & backspace button.

[image]

---

right now the problem is that the output of that directive is firing for all the four datePicker components together and the date is being cancelled on all of them.

here are the code for the directive :

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[atenaAllowDeleteOnly]',
})
export class AllowDeleteOnlyDirective {

  @Output() updatedVal = new EventEmitter(); // emitted Current Value
  constructor(private model: NgModel) { }

  @HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
  keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ((event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46)) {
      this.updatedVal.emit(null);
    }

  }

}
```

DatePicker Component :

```
<div class="input-group body-input">
    <button class="close" type="button"></button>
    <input [readonly]="false" 
           id ="date-{{id}}" 
           atenaAllowDeleteOnly
           (updatedVal)="deleteDate($event)"
           (ngModelChange)="onSelectDate($event)" 
           attr.aria-describedby="{{label}}" 
           class="form-control"
           [class.datePicker-border]="!_isReadOnly" 
           placeholder="gg/mm/aaaa" [name]="name"   
           [(ngModel)]="valueApp" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
    <img src="../../../../../Atena/assets/img/icons/calendar.svg"
         (click)="_isReadOnly ? null :  d.toggle()" alt>
 </div>
```

the deleteDate method is firing for all DatePicker components in the same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your host listener is on `window:keydown`, which means you're listening to all keydown events on the entire window in every directive.

just change it to:

```
@HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
```

to have it be only the element keydown